# Maze Solving - Runtime Error

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error

After I, with some help, got my import_maze function to be working I ran into a problem with my maze_solving function and after 2 hours of experimenting I see no other option than ask for help again. So my maze_solving function is throwing the following Error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 65, in <module>
    solved, solution = maze_solve(startx, starty, maze, solution)
        File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 44, in maze_solve
        solved, temp =  maze_solve(x-1, y, maze, solution)
      File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 34, in maze_solve
        solved, temp = maze_solve(x+1, y, maze, solution)
      File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 34, in maze_solve
        solved, temp = maze_solve(x+1, y, maze, solution)
      File "C:/Users/Anton/PycharmProjects/BWINF_Aufgabe_1/Wegfinden.py", line 27, in maze_solve
        if maze[x][y] == "#" or maze[x][y] == "*":
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Code: http://hastebin.com/owugupicaz.py

Maze:

```
6 9
#########
#  #    #
#  # #  #
#  K #  #
#    #  #
#########
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting stuck in infinite recursion because you are treating paths you have already been marked as potential paths. This is because you aren't marking your path before recurring. Instead of marking the path inside the check for solving, put `maze[x][y]="*"` outside the recursion and solution checks. If you set the bad paths to `" "`, then naturally only the good path will remain marked